# Configuration with name 'integrationTestCompile' not found

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, configuration

when trying to upgrade my gradle version from 5.x to 7.x, getting below error

```
* What went wrong:
Configuration with name 'integrationTestCompile' not found.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
```

Below is my code

```
sourceSets {
    create("integrationTest") {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.test.get().output
    }
}

val integrationTestCompile: Configuration by configurations.getting {
    extendsFrom(configurations.testImplementation.get())
}
val integrationTestRuntimeOnly: Configuration by configurations.getting {
    extendsFrom(configurations.testRuntimeOnly.get())
}

tasks {
    val integrationTest by creating(Test::class) {
        description = "Running integration tests."
        group = "verification"

        testClassesDirs = sourceSets["integrationTest"].output.classesDirs
        classpath = sourceSets["integrationTest"].runtimeClasspath
        shouldRunAfter("test")
    }
}
```

Using gradle with kotlin.

How to fix this?

Comment: unless somebody had the exact same issue as you, so they can tell what needs to be changed, the best thing to do is to read the [release notes](https://gradle.org/releases/) of each version. I'd also suggest to upgrade it version by version, then you can pinpoint which release notes you need to read in full.

Comment: The `compile` configuration has been removed. Consider using `implementation` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In below way you can create `integrationTest` task in gradle latest version

```
configurations {
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    integrationTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom runtimeOnly
}

sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        compileClasspath += configurations['testRuntimeClasspath']
        runtimeClasspath += compileClasspath
    }
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath

    mustRunAfter test
}
```